# infinite threads java

Tags: java, thread-safety, thread-sleep

I need to have a thread which checks for network connection availability on a JAVA desktop app. I got a thread like this

```
    class DataSyncThread extends Thread {
     DataSyncThread() {
     }

     public void run() {
         while(true){
            try{
                System.out.println("Checking for network");
                InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
                if(addr.isReachable(MIN_PRIORITY)){
                    syncData();
                }
                this.sleep(1000000);
            }catch(Exception e){}
         }
     }
 }
```

Now when I call this in the constructer the app never loads. when I look into the console (I trigger the jar to load from it) the thread work, it prints "Checking for network" in the console.

help appreciated

Comment: Your calling code would be helpful here. Also consider a different title for this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My guess is that you're doing something like:

```
DataSyncThread thread = new DataSyncThread();
thread.run();
```

That will run the `run()` method *synchronously*. You should be calling `start()` to create a separate thread of execution:

```
DataSyncThread thread = new DataSyncThread();
thread.start();
```

I would also recommend implementing `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread` - or quite possibly using a `Timer` instead, given that you want periodic execution. I hope your real code has logging in your catch block, too...

Comment: @nivanka: Separation of concerns: you're just trying to give the thread something to run, not change any other aspects of the threading behaviour. Favouring composition over inheritance generally leads to cleaner code.